# Multiple views/controller using ROTATIVA

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, wkhtmltopdf

I am using mvc3 razor.

Is it possible to print multiple views/controllers to create a single pdf using **rotativa**.

Comment: According to the creator of the rotativa package:
"The only thing I can think of is merging the views in a single one, perhaps using Html.RenderPartial."

Comment: http://www.codemag.com/Article/1312081 ? helpful, huh?